# How to add Matplotlib Colorbar Ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

There are many matplotlib colorbar questions on stack overflow, but I can't make sense of them in order to solve my problem.

How do I set the yticklabels on the colorbar?

Here is some example code:

```
from pylab import *
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = np.arange(0,101)                 # frequency 
t = np.arange(11,245)                # time
z = 20*np.sin(f**0.56)+22            # function
z = np.reshape(z,(1,max(f.shape)))   # reshape the function
Z = z*np.ones((max(t.shape),1))      # make the single vector to a mxn matrix
T, F = meshgrid(f,t)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.pcolor(F,T,Z, norm=LogNorm(vmin=z.min(),vmax=z.max()))
plt.xlim((t.min(),t.max()))
mn=int(np.floor(Z.min()))        # colorbar min value
mx=int(np.ceil(Z.max()))         # colorbar max value
md=(mx-mn)/2                     # colorbar midpoint value
cbar=plt.colorbar()              # the mystery step ???????????
cbar.set_yticklabels([mn,md,mx]) # add the labels
plt.show()
```

Comment: I am using eclipse with pydev and sometimes I just paste the code into the python command line. I am not exactly sure what you are suggesting, but I'll look into because it sounds helpful.

Comment: thanks, a good tip to see what methods are available in the future.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Update the ticks and the tick labels:

```
cbar.set_ticks([mn,md,mx])
cbar.set_ticklabels([mn,md,mx])
```

Comment: How come my `mx` ticks is the only one not to be visualized in the colorbar? How can this happen?

Comment: @FaCoffee You need to map the ticks `mn, md, mx` to the interval between 0 and 1 in order to display all tick labels.

Answer (score 10):

A working example (for any value range) with five ticks along the bar is:

```
m0=int(np.floor(field.min()))            # colorbar min value
m4=int(np.ceil(field.max()))             # colorbar max value
m1=int(1*(m4-m0)/4.0 + m0)               # colorbar mid value 1
m2=int(2*(m4-m0)/4.0 + m0)               # colorbar mid value 2
m3=int(3*(m4-m0)/4.0 + m0)               # colorbar mid value 3
cbar.set_ticks([m0,m1,m2,m3,m4])
cbar.set_ticklabels([m0,m1,m2,m3,m4])
```

Answer (score 1):

treenick answer got me started but if your colorbar is scaled between 0 and 1, that code will not plot the ticks if your  `fields` is not scaled between 0 and 1. So instead I used

```
m0=int(np.floor(field.min()))            # colorbar min value
m4=int(np.ceil(field.max()))             # colorbar max value
num_ticks = 10
# to get ticks
ticks = np.linspace(0, 1, num_ticks)
# get labels
labels = np.linspace(m0, m1, num_ticks)
```

If you want spaced out labels you can do python list indexing like so:
assuming skipping every other ticks

```
ticks = ticks[::2]
labels = labels[::2]
```

Comment: This will in most cases give numbers with weird digits like 0.12349956

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like

```
from pylab import *
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = np.arange(0,101)                 # frequency 
t = np.arange(11,245)                # time
z = 20*np.sin(f**0.56)+22            # function
z = np.reshape(z,(1,max(f.shape)))   # reshape the function
Z = z*np.ones((max(t.shape),1))      # make the single vector to a mxn matrix
T, F = meshgrid(f,t)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.pcolor(F,T,Z, norm=LogNorm(vmin=z.min(),vmax=z.max()))
plt.xlim((t.min(),t.max()))
v1 = np.linspace(Z.min(), Z.max(), 8, endpoint=True)
cbar=plt.colorbar(ticks=v1)              # the mystery step ???????????
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(["{:4.2f}".format(i) for i in v1]) # add the labels
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

this would work

```
from pylab import *
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = np.arange(0,101)                 # frequency 
t = np.arange(11,245)                # time
z = 20*np.sin(f**0.56)+22            # function
z = np.reshape(z,(1,max(f.shape)))   # reshape the function
Z = z*np.ones((max(t.shape),1))      # make the single vector to a mxn matrix
T, F = meshgrid(f,t)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.pcolor(F,T,Z, norm=LogNorm(vmin=z.min(),vmax=z.max()))
plt.xlim((t.min(),t.max()))
v1 = np.linspace(Z.min(), Z.max(), 8, endpoint=True)
cbar=plt.colorbar(ticks=v1)              # the mystery step ???????????
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(["{:4.2f}".format(i) for i in v1]) # add the labels
plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65108875/edit) your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of `Eryk Sun`, using only:

```
cbar.set_ticks([mn,md,mx])
cbar.set_ticklabels([mn,md,mx])
```

Will map ticks `mn`, `md` and `mx` to the interval between 0 and 1. For example, if the variables `mn,md,mx` are `0,1,2` then only `mn` and `md` will be shown.

Instead, first define the tick labels and then map the colorbar ticks between 0 and 1:

```
import numpy as np

ticklabels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
cbar.set_ticks(np.linspace(0, 1, len(ticklabels)))
cbar.set_ticklabels(ticklabels)
```