# seaborn clustermap: set colorbar ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like to modify the ticks of a colorbar in a `seaborn.clustermap`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715442/how-to-add-matplotlib-colorbar-ticks) addresses this question for a general `matplotlib` colorbar.

```
g = sns.clustermap(np.random.rand(20,20), 
                   row_cluster=None, col_cluster=None,
                   vmin = 0.25, vmax=1.0)
```

For some reason when I specify `clustermap(..., vmin=0.25, vmax=1.0)`, I get ticks from 0.3 to 0.9, but no 1.0. If I extend `vmax=1.05`, I get a tick precisely at `1.05`.

My guess was that the `g.cax` property of the object returned by `clustermap` is the colorbar, but it has no `.set_ticks()` method.

Any ideas how one can I set the ticks?

Comment: Your question is clear but it would be best if you wrote out an example such that someone could easily copy and paste it to start helping you.

Answer (score 8):

Just like `seaborn.heatmap` the `seaborn.clustermap` has an argument `cbar_kws` (colorbar keyword arguments). This expects a dictionary of possible arguments to the matplotlib colorbar function. Because with matplotlib, we would use the `ticks` argument to colorbar in order to set the ticks manually, we can provide a dictionary like this

```
g = sns.clustermap(..., cbar_kws={"ticks":[0.25,1]})
```

to obtain the tick marks at `0.25` and `1` in the colorbar. (The list can of course be extended, if you want more tickmarks.)

Complete code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

g = sns.clustermap(np.random.rand(20,20), 
                   row_cluster=None, col_cluster=None,
                   vmin = 0.25, vmax=1.0, cbar_kws={"ticks":[0.25,1]})

plt.show()
```

[image]