# How to create a symmetrical colorbar using pcolormesh() in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, flopy

I've been trying to solve this problem for a while, but I'm still struggling, as the Flopy documentation doesn't cover this issue, and I don't have an in depth understanding of pcolormesh() and exactly how it is used by Flopy. I'm trying to create a 2D concentration graph of a contaminant plume. The values of concentration range from 0 to 5000 (mg/l). I would like the lowest concentration, 0, to be represented by white, so I chose the binary colormap for this purpose. I don't know if there is a colormap or method which could show the data better. Since there are so many concentration values, I've found that using a symmetrical log (norm='symlog') helps show the data better. However, when I use this method it ruins the colorbar. How do I make the values on the colorbar symmetrical?

So in short, I want the second graph to have the colorbar on the first graph, with a clearly defined min and max value. How do I do this? Also, is there a better colormap to use which has its lowest value set to white?

[Graph 1, linear scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dx7R0.png)
[Graph 2, symlog scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ds2Kh.png)

Below is the code used to produce each graph. For the first graph norm=norm, and for the second norm='symlog'. I don't know why using the Normalize() method produces a colobar with a defined min and max whereas norm='linear' doesn't, despite the concentration being identical.

`plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))`

`ucnobj = bf.UcnFile('init_plume_ED.UCN')`

`times = ucnobj.get_times()`

`conc = ucnobj.get_data(totim=times[-1])`

`modelmap = flopy.plot.PlotMapView(model=mf, layer=13, extent=(725,925,100,220))`

`norm = Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=5000)`

`cs = modelmap.plot_array(conc, cmap='binary', norm='symlog')`

`cbar = plt.colorbar(cs,shrink=0.2)`

`plt.title('Initial phenol plume concentration (symlog scale)`

The plot_array() function uses kwargs from pcolormesh().

I've tried several methods, like defining the ticks and the min and max tick values; it still doesn't display the values correctly.

Edit: this is what happens when I use `norm='symlog` and use custom tick values and labels as suggested in the first comment.

[Bunched tick labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUUKq.png)

EDIT: I fixed the issue. The problem was that I had negative values (MT3D sets concentration values in dry cells to -1e30) and many small values between 0 and 1. The log scale was preferentially showing the values between 0 and 1; symlog was showing the concentration distribution I wanted (0 to 5000), but its respective colorbar was showing other values. When I used 'ma.masked_equal(concentration_array,-1e30)' it stopped displaying the negative values on the colorbar and started showing the prescribed values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add Matplotlib Colorbar Ticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715442/how-to-add-matplotlib-colorbar-ticks)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. No, it didn't fix the problem. When I set `norm='symlog'` it bunches the tick labels all at the top of the colorbar.

Comment: That's because those values correspond to the colors at the top. When you use a logarithmic color mapping, they will be bunched accordingly.

Comment: Is there a way to show my full array of values [10,100,...5000] and have a symmetrical colorbar?

Comment: You can choose values that are evenly spaced in log10 space.